# Can't load "data.yml" in tests, java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: unit-testing, playframework

I have been playing around with java play framework and following tutorial. While was trying to implement this section "Using Fixtures to write more complicated tests" I faced such an error in tests:

```
A java.lang.RuntimeException has been caught, Cannot load fixture data.yml: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error

In /test/BasicTest.java, line 137 :
Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load fixture data.yml: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:221)
    at BasicTest.fullTest(BasicTest.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$2$1.evaluate(PlayJUnitRunner.java:98)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.run(PlayJUnitRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at play.test.TestEngine.run(TestEngine.java:101)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:540)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:498)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:474)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:469)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:157)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:237)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:217)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.create(GenericModel.java:50)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.bind(JPAPlugin.java:81)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.bind(PluginCollection.java:469)
    at play.data.binding.Binder.bind(Binder.java:309)
    at play.data.binding.Binder.bind(Binder.java:302)
    at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:196)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.edit(GenericModel.java:156)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.create(GenericModel.java:48)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.data.binding.BeanWrapper$Property.setValue(BeanWrapper.java:230)
    at play.data.binding.BeanWrapper.bind(BeanWrapper.java:70)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.edit(GenericModel.java:153)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.sql.Date field models.Post.postedAt to java.util.Date
    at play.data.binding.BeanWrapper$Property.setValue(BeanWrapper.java:225)
    at play.data.binding.BeanWrapper.bind(BeanWrapper.java:70)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.edit(GenericModel.java:153)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.create(GenericModel.java:48)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.bind(JPAPlugin.java:81)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.bind(PluginCollection.java:469)
    at play.data.binding.Binder.bind(Binder.java:309)
    at play.data.binding.Binder.bind(Binder.java:302)
    at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:196)
    at BasicTest.fullTest(BasicTest.java:137)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$2$1.evaluate(PlayJUnitRunner.java:98)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.run(PlayJUnitRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at play.test.TestEngine.run(TestEngine.java:101)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:67)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:540)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:498)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:474)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:469)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:157)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

Lines, where error occurs:

```
@Test
public void fullTest() {
    Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");

    // count everyrhing
    assertEquals(2, User.count());
```

Also I have

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
}
```

But it doesn't help.

data.yml file contains this information, it should be valid cause it was downloaded from official site.

```
# Test data

User(bob):
    email:          bob@gmail.com
    password:       secret
    fullname:       Bob
    isAdmin:        true

User(jeff):
    email:          jeff@gmail.com
    password:       secret
    fullname:       Jeff    

Post(firstBobPost):
    title:          About the model layer
    postedAt:       2009-06-14
    author:         bob
    content:        >
                    The model has a central position in a Play! application. It is the domain-specific 
                    representation of the information on which the application operates.

                    Martin fowler defines it as:

                    Responsible for representing concepts of the business, information about the 
                    business situation, and business rules. State that reflects the business situation 
                    is controlled and used here, even though the technical details of storing it are 
                    delegated to the infrastructure. This layer is the heart of business software.

Post(secondBobPost):
    title:          Just a test of YABE
    postedAt:       2009-03-25
    author:         bob
    content:        >
                    Well, it's just a test.

Post(jeffPost):
    title:          The MVC application
    postedAt:       2009-06-06
    author:         jeff
    content:        >
                    A Play! application follows the MVC architectural pattern as applied to the 
                    architecture of the Web.

                    This pattern splits the application into separate layers: the Presentation 
                    layer and the Model layer. The Presentation layer is further split into a 
                    View and a Controller layer.

Comment(c1):
    author:         Guest
    content:        >
                    You are right !
    postedAt:       2009-06-14
    post:           firstBobPost

Comment(c2):
    author:         Mike
    content:        >
                    I knew that ...
    postedAt:       2009-06-15
    post:           firstBobPost    

Comment(c3):
    author:         Tom
    content:        >
                    This post is useless ?
    postedAt:       2009-04-05
    post:           secondBobPost
```

What mistake have I done?

Comment: Are you sure it's finding data.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you say you solved it by changing the format, but I believe there is another issue here. In your logs there is this message:

```
Can not set java.sql.Date field models.Post.postedAt to java.util.Date
```

It looks to me that your Post class is including java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date, and that may be causing the issue in the first place (formatting being a red herring of the real conflict)

Comment: Thank you, this is the real solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem was in date format in yaml file.
It was 2009/06/06, I just entered 06.06.2009 and everything started working.

Comment: Please accept this answer (even thought its your own) to show the community that this is no longer an issue.